# Difference between Modified Files and Updated Files in CDash

Tags: cmake

When NightlyUpdate is run using GIT, what is the difference between Modified Files and Updated Files in CDash. This seems like it should be an east thing to figure out, but I have been searching for the answer everywhere, but cannot seem to find it.

Comment: Please consider making the title a bit shorter, and adding more of the detail from the title to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Usually only the "Updated files" are meaningful to the continuous integration. The "Modified Files" represents files that have been modified on the local client (submitting to CDash) and that are not in sync with the current repository.